# CodeBuild - Build fails due to missing EC2 Permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, cloudposse

I have a codebuild project that pulls code from Github. I am using [cloudposse](https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-codebuild) template

When I start the build, I get

> VPC_CLIENT_ERROR: Unexpected EC2 error: UnauthorizedOperation

I have found similar problem on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58321632/aws-codebuild-vpc-client-error-unexpected-ec2-error-unauthorizedoperation). But in my case it did not work.

This is my terraform policy:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "permissions" {
  statement {
    sid = ""

    actions = [
      "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
      "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
      "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
      "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
      "ecr:PutImage",
      "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
      "ecs:RunTask",
      "iam:PassRole",
      "logs:CreateLogGroup",
      "logs:CreateLogStream",
      "logs:PutLogEvents",
      "ssm:GetParameters",
      "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
      "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
      "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
      "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
      "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
      "ec2:DetachNetworkInterface",
      "ec2:DescribeDhcpOptions",
      "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
      "ec2:ModifySnapshotAttribute",
      "ec2:ModifyVpcEndpointService",
      "ec2:ResetSnapshot"
    ]

    effect = "Allow"

    resources = [
      "*",
    ]
  }

  statement {
    actions = [
      "ec2:CreateNetworkInterfacePermission"
    ]

    effect = "Allow"

    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "ec2:Subnet"
      values = formatlist("arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/%s", var.subnet_ids)
    }

    condition {
      test = "StringEquals"
      variable = "ec2:AuthorizedService"
      values = ["codebuild.amazonaws.com"]
    }

    resources = [
      "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

And it generates this JSON:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:GetParameters",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "iam:PassRole",
                "ecs:RunTask",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                "ecr:PutImage",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ec2:ResetSnapshot",
                "ec2:ModifyVpcEndpointService",
                "ec2:ModifySnapshotAttribute",
                "ec2:DetachNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DescribeDhcpOptions",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:CreateNetworkInterfacePermission",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:AuthorizedService": "codebuild.amazonaws.com",
                    "ec2:Subnet": [
                        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/subnet-0d121212121212121",
                        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/subnet-0a323232323232323",
                        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/subnet-05454545454545454"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The only way I can make it to work is to add:

> "ec2:*"

I would rather not do that, but fine grain the policy. What policy I need to add to make this work? this is driving me crazy for some time now...

Comment: I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58321632/aws-codebuild-vpc-client-error-unexpected-ec2-error-unauthorizedoperation  
There is a new permission for "ec2:CreateNetworkInterfacePermission" that is needed.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have wildcard in the subnet arn, could you try to change "StringEquals" to "StringLike"? It could be the root cause for this issue. 
Reference for the difference between "StringEquals" and "StringLike" can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html

Thanks!
Xin