# VPC_CLIENT_ERROR: Unexpected EC2 error: InvalidGroup.NotFound

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I encountered this error today on our AWS pipeline, in the CodeBuild Step:

```
VPC_CLIENT_ERROR: Unexpected EC2 error: InvalidGroup.NotFound
```

The only mention of this exact error I could find was here (but it's in Japanese I think) - https://qiita.com/matsuda-hiroki/items/39188d52a002b5461d6f.

I found a similar, but not the same, error here - [AWS CodeBuild VPC_CLIENT_ERROR: Unexpected EC2 error: UnauthorizedOperation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58321632/aws-codebuild-vpc-client-error-unexpected-ec2-error-unauthorizedoperation)

Does anyone know what this means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> VPC_CLIENT_ERROR: Unexpected EC2 error: InvalidGroup.NotFound

This error occurs when your build project is using VPC configuration (passing a VPCID, Subnets, and Security Groups) and the provided Security Group in the VPC Configuration does not exist (as you mentioned it was deleted).

Answer (score 0):

I was eventually told our security team had removed security groups by accident. After they fixed it the error disappeared. I have no idea what the fix entails, though.